# Set gas fee to a fixed value permanently in Metamask

Tags: metamask, gas-price

At present, I can go to the advanced settings and specify the gas fee (in gwei) and gas limit manually. I'd like to make sure that this value is saved and re-used later on for the next few transactions also.

So let's say I configure it now. I want this same fee to be used for the next few hours. Is it possible to do that?

I know that Metamask estimates the gas fee in the ETH network and dynamically updates the (slow, average and fast fields). But I need a way to set it to a custom value and ensure it uses that always.

Comment: This is a question for the Metamask support